# Horizontal pager in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Can we disable the scrolling behaviour for Horizontal Pager in jetpack compose because I am using buttons to scroll the pager

I found that we can do that older versions not in new versions

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
HorizontalPager(
    ....
    userScrollEnabled = false
){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Halifax's answer suffices, I'm assuming that you are using accompanist [Pager API](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) and it is now deprecated because Pager is now available in compose [foundation dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.4.0-alpha03).

to prevent user swipe gesture it has the same parameter `userScrollEnabled = false`.

Thank you.